# Hibernate - best pagination method

Tags: java, hibernate, pagination, scrollableresults

I'm working on a website where I have to show news vertically (one after another). Let's says I have like 100 news and I want to show 10 by 10 just by scrolling. I don't want to remove the first 10 news I've shown, just keep scrolling and adding more news. I've been looking for the right pagination method and I don't know if **ScrollableResults** is the best option for this case or I should go for another option.

This is not a common grid where you move forward ad backward, it is just scrolling down to see more news.

btw I'm using extjs for the client.

Thanks,

PS: I've been looking at this [site](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-pagination)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.Its in java.But you can relate it with your case.

```
query.setFirstResult((searchCriteria.getPageNumber()-1)*searchCriteria.getItemsPerPage());
query.setMaxResults(searchCriteria.getItemsPerPage());
```

where query is ***org.hibernate.Query object***. *ItemsPerPage* is 10 in your case. *PageNumber* you will send from front end as you scroll.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Is that a better approach than using ScrollableResults ?

Comment: First you just relate it with your php code as above is in Java . Whether its possible in php or not?

Comment: Sorry. php tag was added by mistake, it is java!

Comment: OK..then its better.use it.